Why did the "Western World" shift right in post Covid elections?
An interesting phenomenon has emerged since after the Covid-19 pandemic where voters are apparently shifting towards the right.
Examples: The European Union's parliamentary elections showed massive gains for the European right wing. The United States gave the right-wing Republican Party its best popular vote showing and first popular vote victory in 20 years. Canada is set to toss out its Trudeau parliamentary government and vote for its right-wing parties by historic margins according to polls.
Across the so-called West, are people changing their minds and supporting right-wing ideology at higher rates than in the past? Are right-wing individuals turning out at higher rates because of backlash against perceived increases in wokeness?

You have "woke", you have immigration and you also have the constraints imposed by the Covid lockdowns and vaccination mandates.   Add to that inflation and cost of living (which have a climate change adjustment component).  It is hard to say how Western democracies would have evolved with one or more of those factors absent. I suspect some will also blame straight out racism to boot.  So how do you propose to determine which answer is the more correct one?  Largely it'll be down to answerers' opinions about which factor they care to emphasize.
